# using histogram in spark application using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, histogram, pyspark

I was trying to convert a python-spark program to scala application below:

```
  ........................
  ages = user_fields.map(lambda x: int(x[1])).collect()
  hist(ages, bins=20, color='lightblue', normed=True)
  fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
  fig.set_size_inches(16, 10)
```

Below is the corresponding scala code:

```
  var ages = user_data.map(line => line.split('|')(1)).collect
```

Now,I am unable to use histogram here,searched a lot on internet how to make use histogram here and display the graph.I am running my application on intellij.

Any inputs/leads please..

Comment: First of all, it is bad to do a `collect` just to draw a chart, there are some better approaches. Second, you can use `hist` because you loaded `matplotlib` somewhere in your code, but that library doesn't exist in Scala. So, what you need to find is a library to get charts in that language. However, the community version of `databricks` has a nice plot utility, made using D3.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion,I will try to use D3